# How to increase efficiency of web scraping

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I've made a simple app in c# which is using `HtmlAgilityPack` to scrape content by `xPath`. I am just parsing site and extracting chunks.

My basic code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog(); 
    ofd.Filter = ".txt|*.txt";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)  //if I opened a file
    {
        label4.Text = ofd.SafeFileName;
        string line;
        string my_site = textBox1.Text;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName);

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  //load line by line
        {
            try
            {
                var Webget = new HtmlWeb();
                var doc = Webget.Load(line); //obtain source code
                int mine = Convert.ToInt32(scrape_mine(doc, my_site)); //scrape value and convert to Int
                int top = Convert.ToInt32(scrape_top(doc));  //scrape value and convert to Int
                if (top == 0)
                    top = 1;

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(line, top - mine); //add scraped values to dataGrid

            }   //try

            catch (ArgumentNullException)  //if I couldn't scrape value
            {
                try //but source code contains "example"
                {
                    string sourceCode;
                    sourceCode = Worker.getSourceCode(line);
                    Regex r = new Regex(@"(example)");
                    var m = r.Match(sourceCode);
                    if (m.Groups[1].Value.ToString() == "example")
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(line, "ANOTHER");
                    else
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(line, "NONE");
                }


                catch //if I couldn't scrape value and source code does not contains "example"
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(line, "NONE");
                }

            }   //catch

            catch (UriFormatException) //if I couldn't load website
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(line, "WRONG URL");

            }

        }   //while

        countRows(dataGridView1); //function which is sorting extracted data
        MessageBox.Show("Finished!");

    }   //if

}   //button
```

I think I don't need to paste whole code. The thing is, that as you can see I am taking line by line and parsing the each source code. It takes about 15 minutes to parse 5000 url from 1 site (ping ~50ms). Is there any way to reduce the time?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider asking this at [codereview.se]

Comment: If you were to post it on CR remember to include a complete working code =)

Comment: how about simply creating all those vars outside of the while loop and update them as necessary inside the while loop

Comment: In addition, although I am not positive, possibly updating a datasource and then setting the datagridview to that datasource once that loop is finished may also help.

Comment: Oh, thanks. It should decrease time for sure. But i was thinking about threads. Multiple threads with scraping are even worth? I mean if I am using 20 threads, then I am crawling site 20 times slower?